# itertools.permutations not working when repetition is above 9

Tags: python, python-itertools

Why does python itertools.permutations not work when repetition is above 9?

```
for i in itertools.permutations(range(1, 10), 9):
    print(i) # works

for i in itertools.permutations(range(1, 10), 10):
    print(i) # does not work
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations - The number of items returned is n! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n __or zero when r > n.__ (n being the length the passed iterable).

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks. should have checked the docs before i posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(1, 10)` contains 9 elements, the ints from 1 through 9 inclusive. How can the function return a 10-element permutation of a 9-element sequence? Well, it can't, so it doesn't yield anything in that case.

Which means it *does* work: it yields nothing, which is the correct thing to do.